# Facebook like box-WordPress text widget showing in IE but not showing in Firefox and chrome

Tags: facebook, cross-browser, wordpress, text-widget

I'm working on this site for a client http://mohamadelbialy.com/translate, the facebook page url is https://www.facebook.com/translateinegypt my OS is windows 8.1, IE version = 11.0.9600.16521, chrome version = 34.0.1788.0, firefox version = 28.0.

I used the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages to generate an Iframe like box and added the code through a WordPress text widget to show it on pages sidebar (intentionally doesn't show on homepage), if you click on any of the pages, there should be Fb like box on sidebar, however it shows only in IE and I get an empty space on both chrome and firefox.

Interestingly enough, I've done another site for a client two years ago and added fb like box with the same approach and it used to show just fine, now it gives the same results. 
I've tried a couple of plugins like (simple fb plugin - official facebook plugin - and about 3 more) and tried adding the html5 and JDK code instead of Iframe but ended up with the same result.

It looks to me that something is going wrong with the fb-WordPress integration. 
please let me know if you've any solution to this, I can't deliver the website to the client like this. any help will be appreciated.. thanks.

Comment: it worked fine after a few weeks, the only thing I could think of was my windows 8 needed to update